# Parsing XML in Swift

Tags: xml, swift, parsing, attributes, element

Parsing XML in Swift

So the problem is that the first two elements (`i` and `u`) return a value, but other elements return `nil`, I don't know what is the reason

My XML data, I I take from a URL:

```
<root>
    <i><i ok="1" f="Исахан" n="Сәбит" o="Досалыұлы" h="1" e="Бейсембекова Р. Н." ef="" date="20160601"></i></i>
    <u><u g="ВТиПО" s="6M070400"></u></u>
    <p><p p0="Общая успеваемость" p1="Научно-исследов.работа магистранта" p2="Комплексный экзамен" p3="Оформление и защ.магистерс.дисс" p4="Тех. 
облачных вычислений" p5="Компьютерный интеллект" p6="Высокопроизводительные распределенные системы" p7="Технологии разработки программных 
систем" p8="Научно-исследов.работа магистранта" p9="Сетевые технологии" p10="Исследовательская практика" p11="Педагогическая практика" p12=
"Промышленное программирование (МПКС)" p13="Технологии программирования Internet" p14="Научно-исследов.работа магистранта" p15="Технология 
проектирования программных систем" p16="Медиа технологии" p17="Web сервисы" p18="Иностранный язык (профессиональный)" p19="Средства медиа, 
науч.визуализац.и виртуал.реальн." p20="Управление информацией (СТБД)" p21="Научно-исследов.работа магистранта" p22="Психология" p23="История и 
философия науки" p24="Педагогика" pk0=" 0.00"pk0="" pk1="НИРМ" pk2="КЭ" pk3="ОиЗМД" pk4="ТОВ" pk5="КИ" pk6="ВРС" pk7="ТРПС" pk8="НИРМ" pk9="СТ" 
pk10="ИС" pk11="Пед.пр" pk12="ПП" pk13="ТПИ" pk14="НИРМ" pk15="ТППС" pk16="МТ" pk17="WebС" pk18="ИЯ" pk19="СМНВВР" pk20="УИ" pk21="НИРМ" pk22=
"Психолог" pk23="ИиФН" pk24="Педагог."
        total="24">
    </p></p>
    <data><data d0=" 2.48" d1="2015/2016" d2="2015/2016" d3="2015/2016" d4="2015/2016" d5="2015/2016" d6="2015/2016" d7="2015/2016" d8="2015/2016" 
d9="2015/2016" d10="2015/2016" d11="2015/2016" d12="2014/2015" d13="2014/2015" d14="2014/2015" d15="2014/2015" d16="2014/2015" d17="2014/2015" 
d18="2014/2015" d19="2014/2015" d20="2014/2015" d21="2014/2015" d22="2014/2015" d23="2014/2015" d24="2014/2015">
    </data></data>
    <att1><att1 att1_0="0" att1_1=" -" att1_2=" -" att1_3=" -" att1_4="78%" att1_5="86%" att1_6="88%" att1_7="88%" att1_8=" -" att1_9="71%" att1_10=
" -" att1_11=" -" att1_12="93%" att1_13="96%" att1_14=" -" att1_15="85%" att1_16="97%" att1_17="94%" att1_18="95%" att1_19="95%" att1_20="85%" 
att1_21=" -" att1_22="93%" att1_23="88%" att1_24="86%">
    </att1></att1>
</root>
```

I use this code for parsing:

```
func parsing() {
    let parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://service.kazntu.kz/android/android.php?name=514111&pass=514111")!)!
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()
    print(sub)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    parsing()
}

var sub: [String: String]?
var elementNames = [String]()

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
    //I parse only one element, the other did the same way
    if elementName == "p" {
      sub = attributeDict
    }

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: NSError) {
    print(parseError)
}
```

Comment: I think it has something to do with the fact that the ones that are nil are multi-lined and the ones working aren't, but I am not sure

Comment: but first two are working fine

Comment: Yes but they are only 1 line long, the other two probably contain enter characters, like `\n` or `\r` or both and maybe that's the issue

Comment: How to fix this problem?

Comment: you should first write them to a string then do: `var stringWithoutNewLineChar = oldstring.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())`

Comment: This will help? I don't have the possibility to check the code, anyway thank you very much for your response

Comment: I hope it will, I am not sure ;)